# search not functioning correctly after selection in multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two multiple selects in a page (select-cities & chosen-cities), and I can transfer options to and fro. I have given the search functionality to select-cities list. Everything functions as I need.

The problem is when i search in one searchbox and select a few options from the list and move on two the other search box with deleting the typed letters from the first search box, the second search box doesn't function. I am a neophyte hence don't know how to eradicate this problem. I guess it has to do something with the "keyup()" function.

I did the following steps: 
1. first I typed e in #someinput box, and selected three options. 2. the values are now in chosen cities list. 3. Now i tried searching the second search box without deleting the content i typed in the first searchbox. this where the problem starts. It won't work.

here it the demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/cs6Xb/131/

html:

```
<input id="someinput">
<br/>
<select class="select-cities" name="city" id="optlist" multiple="multiple">
    <option>Frederiksberg</option>
    <option>Vanløse</option>
    <option>Glostrup</option>
    <option>Brøndby</option>
    <option>Roskilde</option>
    <option>Køge</option>
    <option>Gentofte</option>
    <option>Hillerød</option>
    <option>Tårnby</option>
    <option>Vallensbæk</option>
</select>
</input>
<br/>
<input id="someinput1"/><br/>

<select class="chosen-cities" name="chosen-cities-name" id="optlist1" multiple="multiple"></select>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    opts = $('#optlist option').map(function () {
        return [[this.value, $(this).text()]];
    });
    opts1 = $('#optlist1 option').map(function () {
        return [[this.value, $(this).text()]];
    });



    $('#someinput').keyup(function () {

        var rxp = new RegExp($('#someinput').val(), 'i');
        var optlist = $('#optlist').empty();
        opts.each(function () {
            if (rxp.test(this[1])) {
                optlist.append($('<option/>').attr('value', this[0]).text(this[1]));
            } else{
                optlist.append($('<option/>').attr('value', this[0]).text(this[1]).addClass("hidden"));
            }
        });
        $(".hidden").toggleOption(false);

    });
        $('#someinput1').keyup(function () {

        var rxp = new RegExp($('#someinput1').val(), 'i');
        var optlist = $('#optlist1').empty();
        opts1.each(function () {
            if (rxp.test(this[1])) {
                optlist.append($('<option/>').attr('value', this[0]).text(this[1]));
            } else{
                optlist.append($('<option/>').attr('value', this[0]).text(this[1]).addClass("hidden"));
            }
        });
        $(".hidden").toggleOption(false);

    });
    $('.select-cities').click(function () {
        $('.select-cities option:selected').remove().appendTo('.chosen-cities');
        opts = $('#optlist option').map(function () {
            return [[this.value, $(this).text()]];
        });
        opts1 = $('#optlist1 option').map(function () {
        return [[this.value, $(this).text()]];
    });
    });

    $('.chosen-cities').click(function () {
        $('.chosen-cities option:selected').remove().appendTo('.select-cities');
        opts = $('#optlist option').map(function () {
            return [[this.value, $(this).text()]];
        });
        opts1 = $('#optlist1 option').map(function () {
        return [[this.value, $(this).text()]];
    });
    });


});

jQuery.fn.toggleOption = function( show ) {
    jQuery( this ).toggle( show );
    if( show ) {
        if( jQuery( this ).parent( 'span.toggleOption' ).length )
            jQuery( this ).unwrap( );
    } else {
        if( jQuery( this ).parent( 'span.toggleOption' ).length == 0 )
            jQuery( this ).wrap( '<span class="toggleOption" style="display: none;" />' );
    }
};
```

Comment: Well, the second search box doesn't work at all… no need to enter text in first… O.o. What is it actually supposed to do..? filter the first selection?

Comment: @TilwinJoy: Yes. The second searchbox will work when you move some values from the first multiselect. Just try the steps which I mentioned in the question. You'll find the problem.

Comment: Um, it works fine for me. I can use both search boxes, even after using the first one - the second searches fine too. Did I misunderstand the problem? it works without deleting the string in the first box.

Comment: @IvyLynx: how manu values did you select?
I guess I am not able to communicate the problem.

Comment: @Kunal lots - tried 3 and more than that, like 5-6.

Comment: @IvyLynx: when I type a string and select values and without deleting the string try to search the second list it doesn't work. :(
do you know the deal with keyup() function?
how does it function?

Comment: @Kunal But I'm telling you, it works fine for me, doing exactly that. I can search with a string, select values, then search the second list whether I delete the first string or not. The code works fine. Try restarting your browser or something, it seems to be a problem on your end, not with the code.

Comment: @IvyLynx: yes you are right.
I was trying in chrome. but it works perfectly fine in mozila.
thankyou..

Comment: @Kunal are you on the latest chrome version? i'm on FF30 but it seems unlikely chrome wouldn't be able to handle something like this.

Comment: @IvyLynx: yes, but I don't know what was the problem. but the solution given below is functioning perfectly. Thanks for your guidance too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was with

```
 $(".hidden").toggleOption(false);
```

I changed the `$(".hidden")` selector based on corresponding `optlist`

```
$("#optlist .hidden").toggleOption(false);
```

and

```
$("#optlist1 .hidden").toggleOption(false);
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cs6Xb/133/)

Comment: thanks a lot sir. It works perfectly in chrome also.